# Angular material table filter testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, dom, angular-material

I'm trying to DOM test filtering of `MatTable` in Angular Material. I have a component named `xxx-table`, with an @Input() named `filter`.

This filter is copied into `dataSource.filter` using onNgChanges, like this:

```js
export class XXXTableComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    @Input()
    loadedDatas: Item[];

    @Input()
    filter: string = '';

  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Suppressed>;

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.suppressedDevices);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

    ngOnChanges(): void {
        if(this.dataSource) this.dataSource.filter = this.filter;
    }
```

[image: My filtered table]
It is working fine in the UI, so I'm trying to DOM test it using `fixture`. 
It seems like it's not updating the DOM in real time. I tried like this:

```js
  it('should filter the dataSource', () => {
    expect.hasAssertions();
    component.filter = 'New York';
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.ngOnChanges();

    expect(component.dataSource.filter).toBe('New York');
    expect(component.dataSource.filteredData.length).toBe(1);

    expect(component.dataSource.filteredData[0].address).toBe(
      '43, Highway Road, 23413'
    );

    // Why isn't that passing?
    return fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      const rows = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');

      expect(rows.length).toBe(1); // Fails here
      const cell = fixture.nativeElement
        .querySelector('tbody td:nth-child(3)')
            expect(cell.textContent)
        .toBe('43, Highway Road, 23413');
    });
  });
```

Comment: The first way to test comes from: 

https://github.com/angular/components/blob/ece800463a6fdb02cc622e964eccd41599c9b5a0/src/material/table/table.spec.ts

I tried waiting 1000ms before testing but it doesn't seems to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

For fixture.whenStable to work you need to wrap your test in async:

```
  it('should filter the dataSource', async(() => {
    expect.hasAssertions();
    component.filter = 'New York';
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.ngOnChanges();

    expect(component.dataSource.filter).toBe('New York');
    expect(component.dataSource.filteredData.length).toBe(1);

    expect(component.dataSource.filteredData[0].address).toBe(
      '43, Highway Road, 23413'
    );

    // Why isn't that passing?
    return fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      const rows = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');

      expect(rows.length).toBe(1); // Fails here
      const cell = fixture.nativeElement
        .querySelector('tbody td:nth-child(3)')
            expect(cell.textContent)
        .toBe('43, Highway Road, 23413');
    });
  }));
```

I'm not exactly sure that's the problem, but I would try that.

Comment: Nice try, but my colleague found the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

So, for future reference, it wasn't working because `fixture.detectChanges();` is called before `component.ngOnChanges();`, so the changes were not detected.

Swapping them fixes the issue.